# How do I host more than one WCF Sequential Workflow in WCF Workflow Library

Tags: wcf, sequential-workflow

I have two workflows in my sequential workflow service library project. But i cannot seem to configure both of the services to run in my wcf service host app. When the service host loads the one service has started but the other is stopped. No amount of fiddling with the app.config file seems to make any difference. How would one configure the hostto support running two WCF Workflows at the same time using the app.config file?

This seems like it would to be easy to configure... just like when you have 2 services running in the same wcf host. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post the relevant part of your config file

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is you can't, if I understand your question.

Each WorkflowServiceHost can host one endpoint with one workflow as the implementation of the service contract.

You can configure them in different WorkflowServiceHosts with different endpoint configurations, though.

```
WorkflowServiceHost host1 = new WorkflowServiceHost(typeof(MyFirstWorkflow), new Uri("URL1"));
WorkflowServiceHost host2 = new WorkflowServiceHost(typeof(MySecondWorkflow), new Uri("URL2"));
host1.Open();
host2.Open();
```

Hopefully this helps.